# Enthought Canopy on Mac OS X installing external program Dolfin (FEniCS)

Tags: python, macos, module, installation, enthought

Over the past few weeks I started programming in Python and have been using Enthought Canopy's python environment (using Mac OS X). I'm interested in modeling incompressible Navier-Stokes equation using the python module FEniCS/DOLFIN, but I have been having problems trying to install it.

Initially, I downloaded DOLFIN for python at: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/DOLFIN/1.2.0 . Inside the DOLFIN folder's Install file, there are steps for a 'Simple build and install' and it says to issue the commands:

```
cmake .
make install
```

So, I downloaded Cmake from: www. cmake .org (assuming all I have to do is download and install it, then I'll be able to reference `cmake` in the terminal).

Then I went into the Mac terminal, went to the location of the DOLFIN folder, and tried the above commands...

```
(Canopy 64bit) Ryans-MacBook-Pro:~ rms1000watt$ cd         
/Users/rms1000watt/Documents/Programs/dolfin-1.2.0

(Canopy 64bit) Ryans-MacBook-Pro:dolfin-1.2.0 rms1000watt$ cmake .
-bash: cmake: command not found

(Canopy 64bit) Ryans-MacBook-Pro:dolfin-1.2.0 rms1000watt$ make install
make: Nothing to be done for `install'.
```

... which clearly didn't work.

So, I thought I would try to just install FEniCS in its entirety from: fenicsproject.org/download/osx_details.html

However, FEniCS is built against system Python and will not work with other Python packages.

(Enthought Canopy provided information to install external packages: https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-external-packages-into-Canopy-Python . But, I figured I was following step 2 by the 'Follow standard python installation procedures from the command line'.)

So, in short, I'm at a loss for how to install DOLFIN into Enthought Canopy.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065082/how-can-i-get-fenics-working-in-ubuntu-12-04-with-epd-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly the cmake executable is not in your PATH; that's why you get the `cmake: command not found` message. Locate your cmake executable with

```
find / -name 'cmake' -perm -111 -type file
```

(on my system the result is `/Applications/CMake 2.8-9.app/Contents/bin/cmake`, for instance; it's likely to be similar on yours). Then run cmake using the full path, e.g.

```
/Applications/CMake\ 2.8-9.app/Contents/bin/cmake .
```

(note the backslash before the space in the directory name). Of course you can also add CMake's `bin` directory to your PATH instead.